# What is the purpose of qlogin?

Tags: linux, unix, qlogin

Does anyone know what the purpose of qlogin is?
I am told to do that even after I log in into the command line window, but was never clear on what the purpose is. I've asked some computer science people, but even they aren't familiar with it. I'm hoping to get some clarification here.

Thanks.

Comment: Using the Qlogin command, you can start a User login session, removing the need to log in for every command.